# Search in datagrid with change in textbox (in wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

The following code can be used if the value buttockno in Table Al is of a string type.
What should I do if the value of buttockno in table Al is numeric?

```
<Window x:Class="DamDarYar_IDMS.Window4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DamDarYar_IDMS"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window4" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="151,44,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="112" Width="211"/>

</Grid>
```

```
    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IDMS_dbEntities db = new IDMS_dbEntities();

        try
        {
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = db.tblAIs.Where(a => a.ButtockNo.StartsWith(textBox.Text.Trim())).ToList();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So you want to do a substring match on a `number`? Can you update your question to show some examples of numbers and which textbox values you would expect it to match it, and which wouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2) for that but using your method simply convert to string first.

```
a.NumericProperty.ToString().StartsWith(...
```